How do I write this Postgres in Pandas
select *
    round(avg(_cluster)::numeric/60,1) as avg_gat
from df;

This is my attempt:
    df['avg_gat'] = (round(df['_cluster'].mean(), 1))


I don't know how to implement this line:
    ::numeric/60

Thanks!

It would be useful to provide a [mre] as example input and the matching expected output

You;re close, maybe try: df['avg_gat'] = round(df['_cluster'].mean() / 60, 1)

There will be a slight difference between avg(_cluster)/60 and avg(_cluster/60) if the precision of your values is close enough to what the underlying data type can hold. See this demo. With the rounding in place, it might be insignificant.
